# Android immersive mode for dropdown, hide navigation Bar

Tags: android, android-spinner, popupwindow, android-immersive, android-navigation-bar

added listview to PopupWindow object, on click Navigation key bar is popping, is there is a way to block navigation bar on click of dropdown.

Answer (score 1):

try this snippet inside on onclick of drop down item

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
// Hide both the navigation bar and the status bar.
// SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN is only available on Android 4.1 and higher, but as
// a general rule, you should design your app to hide the status bar whenever you
// hide the navigation bar.
int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
              | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
```

and refer [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE) and [here](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html)